# Не работает vector sort, нестандартный синтаксис

Tags: c++, сортировка, vector

Перепробовал уже тонну всего, никак не могу разобраться, что именно не так. Я просто хочу отсортировать класс по brand и model используя алгоритм sort.

Car.cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Car {
public:
    string brand;
    string model;
    unsigned int year_of_issue;
    double engine_capacity;
    double price;
    string vin;

    void operator()() {
        cout << endl;
        cout << brand << " " << model << endl;
        cout << "Year: " << year_of_issue << endl;
        cout << "Engine: " << engine_capacity  << "cm3" << endl;
        cout << "Price: " << price  << "$" << endl;
        cout << "VIN: " << vin << endl;
    }

    Car(string brand, string model, unsigned int year_of_issue, double engine_capacity, double price, string vin) {
        this->brand = brand;
        this->model = model;
        this->year_of_issue = year_of_issue;
        this->engine_capacity = engine_capacity;
        this->price = price;
        this->vin = vin;
    }
        
};
```

CarDataBaseController.cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 
#include "Car.cpp"


class CarDataBaseController {
private:
    vector<Car> cars;
    vector<Car>::iterator iter;

public:

    bool equalsByPrice(const Car &a, const Car &b) {
        return a.price > b.price;
    }

    CarDataBaseController() {

    }
    void addCar(Car car) {
        cars.push_back(car);
    }
    void addCar(string brand, string model, unsigned int year_of_issue, double engine_capacity, double price, string vin) {
        Car car(brand, model, year_of_issue, engine_capacity, price, vin);
        cars.push_back(car);
    }


    void getAllCars() {
        for (Car car : cars) {
            car();
        }
    }


    void sortByPrice() {
        sort(cars.begin(), cars.end(), equalsByPrice);
        getAllCars();
    }


};
```

AutoRia.cpp:

```
    #pragma once
#include "CarDataBaseController.cpp"

int main()
{
    Car car("Kia", "Sportage", 2015, 2500, 15000, "ISO 3779 - 1983");
    Car car4("Kia", "Rio", 2020, 3100, 25000, "ISO 3134 - 1912");
    Car car3("BMW", "i7", 2020, 3000, 50000, "ISO 7144 - 9012");
    Car car2("Mercedes-Benz", "Benz GLE-Class 350", 2017, 3500, 42500, "ISO 5154 - 1912");

    CarDataBaseController cdbc;
    cdbc.addCar(car);
    cdbc.addCar(car2);
    cdbc.addCar(car3);
    cdbc.addCar(car4);
    cdbc.getAllCars();
    cout << "\n\nAfter Sorting:\n";
    cdbc.sortByPrice();
}
```

[image: Наша ошибка]

Comment: Напишите короткий, но **законченный!** cpp файл, где воспроизводится проблема. А то там где-то какой-то еще класс Controller в диагностике виден. Из класса `Car` можно временно убрать все геттеры/сеттеры.

Comment: @AlexTitov посмотрите сейчас, так будет лучше? Убрал, вроде как, все лишнее

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72260619/6944845

Comment: Вообще осталась туча замечаний по коду: 1. обычно cpp не включают, да и эти файлы у вас по смыслу заголовки (.h, или .hpp). 2. Все константные методы должны иметь квалификатор `const` 3. В имеющихся функциях все объекты класов передавать в параметрах через `const ... &` 4. Посмотрите, как записывается коструктор с инициализацией значений, там чуть проще, чем у Вас. 5. добавление машины по списку всех параметров в одну строчку через `еmplace_back`

Comment: @AlexTitov Спасибо большое, учту, сам не пишу на плюсах, попросил друг помочь, вот и немного кашица)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теперь понятно :) `bool equalsByPrice` надо просто "вынести" из класса .(можно объявить static в класе, но смысла нет).

Comment: Я сейчас заплачу от счастья, спасибо!